# Update all keys with a specific prefix in Newtonsoft JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can I update all keys with a given prefix at all levels in a JObject with a specific value? e.g.

```
{
  "nameOne": "dave",
  "age": 23,
  "foo": {
    "nameTwo": "pete",
    "age": 56
  }
}
```

How can I update nameOne and nameTwo (name*) to "chris"?

Comment: could you show your class(es) linked to the json?

Comment: @Frenchy There are no other classes. It's simply a JObject created using the Parse() method:

_settings = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(SettingsFile));

Comment: And how many levels has your object and pls show us what you have done so far and where is the error or problem?

Comment: @Serge It goes no deeper than my example. I don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

if it goes no deeper than in your example you can try this

```
 _settings = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(SettingsFile));

_settings["nameOne"]="cris";
_settings["foo"]["nameTwo"]="cris";
```

or if you need some search, try this

```
    var searchString = "name";
    var newValue = "cris";

    foreach (var property in _settings)
    {
        var key = property.Key;

        if (property.GetType().Name != "JObject")
        {
            if (key.Contains(searchString)) _settings[key] = newValue;
        }
        else
        {
            JObject prop = _settings[key] as JObject;
            foreach (var nestedProperty in prop)
            {
                var nestedKey = nestedProperty.Key;
                if (nestedKey.Contains(searchString)) prop[nestedKey] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

instead of Contains  you can use StartWith or EndsWith as well

it was tested in visual studio

```
{
  "nameOne": "cris",
  "age": 23,
  "foo": {
    "nameTwo": "cris",
    "age": 56
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to update all keys that match a specific pattern, e.g. all keys that begin with "name".